# Ghostcript Converting PDF from RGB to CMYK also produces DeviceGray object

Tags: ghostscript

I'm trying to use Ghostscript to convert PDF files which have RGB colors into CMYK colors. The blue colors in my PDF get converted into DeviceCMYK just fine. However, pure white colors (i.e. RGB 255, 255, 255) don't show up in the CMYK separation when I do Output Preview in Adobe Acrobat. When I use Acrobat's Object Inspector, it reveals that my white colors have ColorSpace=DeviceGray and ColorValues=1.0 (i.e. white).

This is the simplest form of the command I'm using:

```
ghostscript\gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -sOutputFile="cmyk.pdf" "rgb.pdf"
```

I would like to force these white colors to be ColorSpace=DeviceCMYK and ColorValues=0, 0, 0, 0.  (This is what Acrobat's Convert Colors produces). How can I do that? I tried hunting through the documentation and trying out various switches that I didn't fully understand, but the result was always the same so far.
If it matters, the version of Ghostscript is 9.21

Input and output files can be downloaded here: https://ufile.io/f/faxbb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, you can't do that. The pdfwrite device regards DeviceGray as a subset of CMYK (it's the K channel) and if it finds a DeviceGray colour it will retain it as such. However, true RGB colours ought to be converted to CMYK.

You haven't supplied the original file so I can't inspect it or try it.

You should upgrade, 9.21 is 3 years old, 9.53.0 was released today.

### Edit

I checked the code and this is actually an optimisation. C=M=Y=0, K=% or R=G=B are converted into DeviceGray when written out (ONLY if you are using ColorConversion though!). This is because a single component floating point is smaller to write than three floating point values, so you get a smaller PDF file.

If any profession printing service fails to print colours in DeviceGray I'd be shocked. I'd also be looking for a new printer!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Ok, good to know not to bang my head against the wall trying to change that then.

A follow-up question I have then is whether or not a PDF with both DeviceCMYK and DeviceGray objects is completely ready to be professionally printed. Like, is there any chance the printer will print only the DeviceCMYK objects and not the DeviceGray ones?

Comment: I added a link to an input file that will reproduce the condition. Thanks!